# How to start Intel Power Gadget in Batch Script?

Tags: batch-file, intel

On the Intel page it says that you can start the log with the commands "-start" and "-stop". I have already tried different variants, but I can't get it to run.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/power-gadget.html?wapkw=intel%20power%20gadget

My goal is to start the log at the beginning of the batch script, then measure the energy consumption of a test application and stop the log at the end.

Here is an example from the file:

```
SET IPG=C:\Program Files\Intel\Power Gadget 3.6\IntelPowerGadget.exe

START "" "%IPG%" -start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out for myself. It seems that the program did not start because the process was running too fast and thus could not be executed completely. Have now added a timeout.

```
SET IPG=C:\Program Files\Intel\Power Gadget 3.6\IntelPowerGadget.exe

START "" "%IPG%"

timeout /t 5 

START "" "%IPG%" -start

....

START "" "%IPG%" -stop
```

Maybe it helps someone.